# Action behind self created button won't work.

Tags: xcode, uibutton, action, css-selectors

I've got a simple problem but I don't know why it doesn't work. 
I created a button programatically and I'd like to add the method "backLogin" to the action. 
Strange enough, I don't get any errors, but the button just won't respond in any way. Anywhere I look on the internet, this code should definitely work. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
-(void) loginAppear{

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 75, 37); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
[myButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
// add to a view
[myButton setAlpha:1];
[loginImage addSubview:myButton];      
}
```

The code behind "backLogin" has already worked in other circumstances:

```
-(void) backLogin{

CALayer *layer = loginImage.layer;    

//spin frame
CABasicAnimation *anim1 =
[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform" ];
anim1.toValue = [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:
                 CATransform3DMakeRotation(180 * M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0) ];
anim1.duration = .2;
anim1.cumulative = YES;
anim1.repeatCount = 1;
[layer addAnimation: anim1 forKey: @"transformAnimation" ];       

}
```

Comment: have you tried putting an NSLog in your backLogin method, to confirm if the method is called... perhaps the code there is not working

Comment: What is loginImage? Do you get any visual indication that the button was pressed?

Comment: Hello, loginImage is a UIImageView instance. I will try the NSLog now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding myButton to loginImage, try adding it to the main view (e.g. [self.view addSubview:myButton]). You may need to change the frame coordinates to position the button properly.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I get a reaction from my button, but an error; [loginViewController backLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ad2c0 I don't see any mistakes though... ?

Comment: The : in [loginViewController backLogin:] would seem to indicate that it expects backLogin to be a function that takes one parameter. Perhaps you need: -(void) backLogin:(UIButton *)sender. And for addTarget call use @selector(backLogin:).

Comment: Better yet, change backLogin to: -(void) backLogin:(id) sender